# Setting disassembly flavour to Intel in LLDB

Tags: gdb, llvm, lldb

Is there a way to set the disassembly flavour like there is in GDB within LLDB so that it spits out Intel style assembly rather than AT&T style?

```
set disassembly-flavor intel # GDB
```

but for LLDB.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, not yet.  Intel format disassembly is a feature I'm sure will be implemented eventually, but I don't think anyone is working on it today.

**UPDATE**: the ability to select the assembly style was added to the top of tree sources (v. http://lldb.llvm.org ) March 1st, 2013 with the `-F` or `--flavor` option to disassemble or the `target.x86-disassembly-flavor` setting in your `~/.lldbinit` file.  This will be available in future releases of lldb in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I do hope that it is being worked on, Intel syntax is much more readable than AT&T GAS syntax.

Comment: yah, whichever you're familiar with is the one you prefer - the people who have always used the AT&T syntax find the Intel one hard to read. :)  lldb uses the disassembler from llvm - I'm sure someone will eventually be sufficiently motivated to add Intel formatted disassembly support to llvm.

Comment: I know this is late, but I just got ino lldb debugging a few days ago.  I normally see Intel syntax and am happy with that, but just now I used a GDB command (x -s8 -fx -c4 0x0000000100004024) and that command was understood by LLDB to mean I preferred AT&T syntax.  so is there a command I can type into an LLDB session to revert syntax?  I just did a couple of step commands and Intel is back.  So,  n-e-v-e-r    m-i-n-d.

Answer (score 62):

The exact line to write in your `~/.lldbinit` file is

```
settings set target.x86-disassembly-flavor intel
```

In the future, you will also be able to tweak how immediate values are displayed with the [new settings: target.use-hex-immediates and target.hex-immediates-style](https://web.archive.org/web/20140907195913/http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/lldb-commits/Week-of-Mon-20130805/009226.html).

Comment: You da real MVP