# Intel-syntax Assembly in Xcode debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging, assembly, x86, disassembly

I am trying to get Xcode to display the assembly code while debugging in the Intel format. I have tried to add the flag **-masm=intel** in the "Other C Flags" section under Build Settings but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12768024/2189500)?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Nope.  This is about setting up the C compiler.

Comment: Once you have machine code, all that matters is *dis*assembler settings in your debugger, not compiler options.  In GDB, it's `set disassembly-flavor intel` (or `att`).  Look for something similar in Xcode's debugger, which I think uses LLDB.