# Is there a way to specify syntax for x command output?

Tags: assembly, x86, lldb, disassembly, intel-syntax

I want to know whether I can change the syntax of the output of the following command:

```
x/5i $rip
```

Now it gives output like that. I guess it is AT&T syntax, correct my if I'm wrong (newbie):

```
->  0x100000f96: bf 01 00 00 00  movl   $0x1, %edi
    0x100000f9b: be 02 00 00 00  movl   $0x2, %esi
    0x100000fa0: ba 03 00 00 00  movl   $0x3, %edx
    0x100000fa5: b9 04 00 00 00  movl   $0x4, %ecx
    0x100000faa: e8 b1 ff ff ff  callq  0x100000f60               ; test_func at main.c:4
```

What I want is to something like `-F` flag in the following command `disassemble -n main -F intel`. Is there any way to achieve that. I have not found anything neither using `help x` nor by googling. Thanks in advance!

Note: I am using `lldb` as a debugger.

Comment: No idea about `lldb` but in `gdb` you can `set disassembly-flavor intel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Jester for a clue. I have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21502943/10347620).

> ```
> settings set target.x86-disassembly-flavor intel
> ```

This will work for `x` command as well.

Comment: If you put this^ in `~/.lldbinit` it will automatically happen on every launch of lldb.